# Trocando ícones no botão menu não mostra

Tags: html, css, menu

Estou tentando trocar os ícones, mas não mostra

Fonte do menu
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/

Código CSS Original

```
.icon-team, .icon-blog, .icon-home, .icon-portfolio, .icon-services, .icon-contact, .icon-menu {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-team:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

Código HTML com CSS modificado

```css
.icon-barcode,
.icon-blog,
.icon-home,
.icon-portfolio,
.icon-services,
.icon-contact,
.icon-menu {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-barcode:before {
  content: "\e937";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="icon">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-barcode"></i>
</span>
  <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

Comment: O que deveria ser `\e937`?

Comment: Este número é o ícone do código de barra que seria o icon-barcode @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @Angelino cara dei uma editada na resposta e tentei colocar todos os detalhes, mas se vc tiver alguma dúvida é só dar o toque que te dou uma força

Comment: Obrigado Resolvido @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angelino na própria documentação do link que vc citou fala que a primeira coisa a fazer é preparar a font de ícones...

> The first thing we need to do is to create the icons for the menu.

No caso ele usou a `icomoon.io` vc tem que entrar lá, selecionar os itens que precisa e gerar as fontes conforme as imagem https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Primeiro vc escolhe os ícone e depois faz o download. Então logicamente a fonte só tem os caracteres que vc selecionou antes de gerar os arquivos `.ttf` `.otf` etc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Veja abaixo os ícone da fonte que eu gerei!**

```css
body {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/style.css">

<i class="icon-office"></i>
<i class="icon-pacman"></i>
<i class="icon-file-play"></i>
<i class="icon-file-video"></i>
<i class="icon-coin-euro"></i>
```

**CSS Completo gerado pelo próprio Icomoon** Repare nos código que ele gerou para os ícones no `content: "\e93c"` etc.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?9rw8st');
  src:  url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/icomoon.eot?9rw8st#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/icomoon.ttf?9rw8st') format('truetype'),
    url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/icomoon.woff?9rw8st') format('woff'),
    url('https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/c4dd1abf17/UntitledProject/icomoon.svg?9rw8st#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-office:before {
  content: "\e903";
}
.icon-pacman:before {
  content: "\e916";
}
.icon-file-play:before {
  content: "\e929";
}
.icon-file-video:before {
  content: "\e92a";
}
.icon-coin-euro:before {
  content: "\e93c";
}
```